# Compilation from source

Tags: magento2

Upon running full build, the site broke with the error in the image. Everything was working fine.

[image]

Comment: 1: Run rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/* Then, 2: sudo chmod 777 var/ pub/static/ generated/ 3: At last Run compilation

Comment: you can try run command with additional param (-vvv)